# How can I get the TypeScript layer for Spacemacs to do type-checking?

Tags: spacemacs

I'm using the [TypeScript layer for Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Blang/typescript). Type information, go-to-definition, completions, etc. all work great.

But if I do this:

```
const x: string = 3;
```

Nothing yells at me about the type error. Why? How can I get this feature? It's essential to TypeScript development.